# Symfony routing and config components

Tags: php, symfony

Atm i am trying to migrate php code

```
$routes->add(
    'index',
    new Route('/', ['_controller' => 'getIndex'])
);
```

to YML config

```
index:
    path:   /
    defaults: { _controller:  'getIndex' }
```

but i am getting an error

```
'There is no extension able to load the configuration for "index" (in /app/config\routes.yml).
```

YamlFileLoade just cant read this type of config, but why? I am using this guide http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html and my code to load configurations

```
$config = array(__DIR__ . '/app/config');
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator($config));
$loader->load('master.yml');
$collection = $loader->load('routing.yml');
```

already working perfectly with service container (master.yml) but doesnt with routings configuration.

Comment: Your routing needs to be in `app/config/routing.yml` or in added bundles. <-- That's for Symfony, ignore this~

Comment: Are you using the correct YamlFileLoader (`Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader`)? Also your `$loader->load('master.yml')` doesn't match your `routes.yml` filename.

Comment: routing.yml is already in config folder, i just gave an example with master.yml to say what YamlFileLoader working for another configuration file, but doesn't for routing.yml :) Updated code to avoid misunderstoods.

Comment: Are you using the correct YamlFileLoader read it? The services one will only allow parameters or services while the routing one will allow routes.

Comment: @Qoop please add this as an anwser, and i ll mark it, you are right, they have similar names, and i am using YamlFileLoader of DI component, not Routing one.

Comment: Strange. `YamlFileLoader::load()` doesn't return anything. Why are the docs assigning it to a variable? Also, the error suggests that `ContainerBuilder::$extensions` array doesn't contain `yml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting comment as answer as requested...*

Are you using the correct YamlFileLoader read it? The services (DI) one will only allow parameters or services while the routing one will allow routes.

Routing => `Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader`

DI => `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader`

Comment: We can not use the loader  Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader
in Symfony\Component\ DependencyInjection\Extension. See Wouter J 's  answer to find out how.

Answer (score 2):

At first routing configuration is something different than DI configuration. You are now trying to load routes using the DI config mechanism.

To use routes, you should create a file `app/config/routing.yml`. This is where the routes life. If you want to put the routes in the bundle, you cannot use the DI extension class to load them. You have to include them in the `app/config/routing.yml` file, like this:

```
acme_demo_routes:
    resource: @AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml
```